# Is the account 'eosio.stake' a service that's holding over 51% of the EOS?

Tags: staking, rich-list

Looking up the largest holder of EOS, its the account: https://eosflare.io/account/eosio.stake

Is this a service and what does it do? And how did it acquire 51% of the stake and does it pose a problem?

Comment: it's just the amount of staked tokens from users... when you stake, your eos goes there